# Example of a non-normal family of meromorphic functions defined on the unit disk whose derivative is normal.

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions, normal-families

It is well known that if a family of meromorphic functions is not normal ( a family of meromorphic functions is said to be normal if each sequence of functions in the family has a subsequence which converges locally uniformly to a limit function which is either meromorphic or identically $\infty$ ), then the corresponding family of derivatives may or may not be normal.

For example, $\mathcal{F}:=\{f_n= nz, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not normal on $|z|<1.$ However, the corresponding family of derivatives $\mathcal{F'}=\{n\}$ is normal on $|z|<1.$

Here is my problem:

I am looking for a family of meromorphic functions whose each zero is of multiplicity $2$ and which is not normal on $|z|<1.$ But the corresponding family of derivatives is normal.

Any help shall be largely appreciated.

Comment: No $f_n$'s should have zeros of multiplicity $2.$

Comment: I don't see where is the problem in the example. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes it does, but there is a catch. A family of meromorphic functions is normal if any sequence in that family converges locally uniformly to a limit function which is either meromorphic or identically $\infty.$ In my example, the family of derivatives converges to  the constant limit $\infty$

Comment: I think I see, you meant $f_n(z) = [nz:1]=[g_n(z):1] \in \Bbb{P}^1$ with $g_n$ meromorphic and $f_n'(z)=[g_n'(z):1]=[n:1]$, the latter is normal whereas $f_n$ is not. Please clarify your question this way.

Comment: If you observe closely, I have written explicitly that $f_n=\{nz\}$ is not normal on the unit disk, however $f_n\prime=\{n\}$ is normal.

Comment: Doesn't $n$ converges uniformly to $\infty$?

Comment: @reuns Normality has different definitions. The OP is using it to mean normality in the meromorphic sense, i.e. precompact in $\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{S})$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is equipped with the cordal metric.

Comment: absolutely right @Caffeine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is negative.
This follows easily from the following result of Chen and Lappan (Adv. Math.,vol. 24, 1996, 517-524):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of meromorphic functions in a domain $D$ such that each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ has zeros of multiplicity at least $k+1,$ where $k$ is a positive integer. If the family $\mathcal{G}=\left\{f^{(k)}:f\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ is normal in $D,$ then $\mathcal{F}$ is also normal in $D.$